# Universal Windows Platform and SignalR (Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net, Version=2.0.5.0)

Tags: c#, windows, signalr, win-universal-app, visual-studio-2015

when using the new Universal Windows Platform and a SignalR client (from Nuget) a strange thing happens when you set the network credential.

The following code works flawlessly:

```
NetworkCredential Connection_Credentials = new NetworkCredential( "Name", "Password" );
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection Connection = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection( "http://localhost/Bla" );
```

However when you assign the NetworkCredential in the following way the runtime crashes even before executing the code:

```
NetworkCredential Connection_Credentials = new NetworkCredential( "Name", "Password" );
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection Connection = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection( "http://localhost/Bla" );
Connection.Credentials = Connection_Credentials;
```

The error is: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.\r\n   at UAP2.MainPage.Page_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)"

Is this an error I can fix myself (I tried doing the same with another project) or is there a problem in the SignalR package (or one of it's dependencies?).
Why would it want to reference 2.0.5.0 of System.Net and not a 4-* version?

Comment: Is it **a new** universal store app project or you are upgrading changing an existing project? 2.0.5.0 indicates Silverlight (or Siverlight based WP app).

Comment: It is actually a brand new UAP (or UWP) app created from the new template in Visual Studio 2015 RC.
For the new project I merely added a Loading subscription on the MainWindow, installed the SignalR Client Nuget package and put the three lines in the OnLoading method.  
I have uploaded the solution to:  
http://skyseract.com/Storage/UAP3.zip

Comment: Instead of tagging very generic terms like `.net` or `uap`, you'd get better results tagging this `visual-studio-2015`.

Comment: @zeroskyx I will take a look at this on Monday.

Comment: Can't even build an UAP. Tried on two different boxes. Windows SDK is installed but VS is saying "Could not find SDK "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime, Version=1.0". I tried yours and also created a new one - the same result. Sorry.

Comment: Same Problem here. Added an UAP project to an existing and working solution, where I was able to write a Windows 8.1 Universal app without problems. Getting the same exception. Also, we tried with a fresh UAP project, same result. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a bit crude, but I have found a fix/workaround. Basically you have to make sure you use the assembly from the WinRT project in stead of the two that NuGet attaches. See http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.nl/2015/05/getting-signalr-clients-to-work-on.html for details

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the answer to the problem, but I reported an issue about it on GitHub. Hopefully someone will finally look into it.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3483

Edit:

Did some testing with the source code of SignalR.Client and it crashes in its `DefaultHttpHandler(IConnection connection)` constructor. Most likely when in `System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler` constructor (for which I don't have source code).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this should be to compile the SignalR client DLL without support for SL5 - targeting .NET 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone Silverlight 8, and Windows Phone 8.1, also known as PCL Profile 259.

Comment: Like I already wrote on Github, this results in an over all unbuildable project as too many dependencies get broken.